# When we can get EGAIN error

Tags: networking, tcp

Hi
I am using a non blocking socket .But while sending messages I am gettng EAGAIN error occasionally.

Can you please tell me what are the situation we may get EGAIN error .As I have set the buffer size also with good amount of value .And i am just sending 18 messages of 20 bytes.So I dont think its giving EGAIN because of buffer full.Any other reason it may happen.

Or how to analyse what reason has cause the EAGAIN error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAGAIN just means 'try again'. So just do that. Regardless of the reason. You can't do anything about the reason, but you can do what EAGAIN tells you to do.